# Prove that $ta+(1-t)b\in R$ for $a,b\in R$ and $t\in [0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis

I have that $R$ is the rectangle $R=[\alpha,\beta]\times[\gamma,\delta]\ and\ a=(a_1,a_2), b=(b_1,b_2)$
$$\alpha\leq a_1\leq \beta, \gamma \leq a_2 \leq \delta$$ because $a\in R$
and
$$\alpha\leq b_1\leq \beta, \gamma \leq b_2 \leq \delta$$
because $b\in R$.

I need to show that $ta+(1-t)b\in R$.

Comment: Welcome to StackMath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that: $ta+(1-t)b=t(a_1,a_2)+(1-t)(b_1,b_2)=(ta_1+(1-t)b_1,ta_2+ (1-t)b_2) \tag 1$

Note that $\alpha\leq a_1\leq \beta, \gamma \leq a_2 \leq \delta\implies t\alpha\leq ta_1\leq t\beta, t\gamma \leq ta_2 \leq t\delta$

Similarly,  $\alpha\leq b_1\leq \beta, \gamma \leq b_2 \leq \delta\implies (1-t)\alpha\leq (1-t)b_1\leq (1-t) \beta, (1-t)\gamma \leq (1-t)b_2 \leq (1-t)\delta$

Add the above inequalities to get: $(1-t)\alpha+t\alpha\leq (1-t)b_1+ta_1\leq (1-t) \beta+t\beta \implies \alpha\le (1-t)b_1+ta_1\le \beta$  
Similarly, from the rest two inequalities, you get $\gamma\le ta_2+ (1-t)b_2 \le \delta$

Hence proved. (By $(1)$)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: let $c=(c_1,c_2)=ta+(1-t)b$, then you need to show $c_1\in[\alpha,\beta]$ and $c_2\in[\gamma,\delta]$, so 4 inequalities in total. For example:
$$
\beta=t\beta+(1-t)\beta\geq\underbrace{ta_1+(1-t)b_1}_{c_1}\geq t\alpha+(1-t)\alpha=\alpha.
$$